# Does "Advanced Custom Fields" taxonomy field support user pages?

Tags: wordpress, foreach, advanced-custom-fields

I have a "taxonomy" custom field for the user pages. I want to build a query filtered by this field. It works with normal querys but not with user-querys, am i doing something wrong?

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'key' => 'fruits', 
        'value' => 'apple'
);

// The Query
    $user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );

// User Loop
    if ( ! empty( $user_query->results ) ) {
        foreach ( $user_query->results as $user ) {
        echo $user->display_name;
        }
    } else {
    echo 'No users found.';
}
?>
```

Comment: Custom Field Parameters

Show users associated with a certain custom field.

The WP_Meta_Query class is used to parse this part of the query since 3.2.0, so check the docs for that class for the full, up to date list of arguments.

    meta_key (string) - Custom field key.
    meta_value (string) - Custom field value.

Comment: Vrajesh is right answer (y)

Answer (score 1):

Try `get_users` instead:

```
$users = get_users(array(
    'meta_key' => 'fruits',
    'meta_value' => 'apple'
));
var_export($users);
```

Wordpress codex: [get_users()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users)

#### Edit:

After a bit of research it turns out that `get_users()` is only a wrapper for `WP_user_query`, so switching to this function will make no difference.

However... did you notice that in my answer (and vrajesh') we have substituted your `key` with `meta_key`, and `value` with `meta_value` ... They are definitely defined in the `WP_User_Query` class, so I would be surprised if they didn't have any meaning.

If by chance you are using your original `$args` (which I guess does not actually refer to fruits and apples), then that may well be the explanation you are getting nothing.

Comment: No luck with this. I think taxonomies are not supported for users.

Comment: "meta_key" works with users but not with a taxonomy field only with normal fields.

Comment: Ok, I'm giving up for now. If it remains unsolved I may give it a shot when I can actually run some tests, but clearly stabbing in the dark is not paying off :p If it really isn't possible with builtin query functions you can always resort to direct database queries, though obviously it will be much more complicated and less future-proof.

Comment: Yes, and for a direct database query i have to call my backend programmer ;)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$args = array( 'meta_key' => 'fruits', 'meta_value' => 'apple','compare' => '=');
```

Comment: I already tried this but it doesn't work ("No users found."). This works with normal ACF fields but not with the "taxonomy" field.

Comment: Same problem. Btw. compare with what?

Comment: @HenningFischer `compare` is the comparison operator (ie. `meta_key` needs to be `=` to `meta_value`). See [Meta_query compare operator explanation](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/70864/meta-query-compare-operator-explanation)

Comment: Okay, but in a normal (not user- ) query this works without "compare".

Comment: have you got solution?..:)

Comment: Well as far as I know the default compare operator is `=` anyway, so I don't really think it makes any difference whether or not you specify it explicitly... I don't have time to actually try to solve this right now, I just wanted to chime in with a quick explanation of the `compare` parameter.

Comment: @vrajesh: I think taxonomy field is just not supported for users.

Answer (score 0):

Use WP_Query instead of WP_User_Query. WP_User_Query is used to retrieve data from user and usermeta table. And according to my understanding your are retrieving data from posts and postmeta table.
[Class Reference/WP User Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query) and 
[Class Reference/WP Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

UPDATED:

Try this

```
<?php
     $args = array(
      'meta_query' => array(
        'key' => 'fruits', 
        'value' => 'apple',
        'compare' => '='
      )  
 );

// The Query
   $user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );

// User Loop
    if ( ! empty( $user_query->results ) ) {
        foreach ( $user_query->results as $user ) {
           echo $user->display_name;
         }
    } else {
    echo 'No users found.';
 }
?>
```

Comment: No, as i said it is a user-query because the taxonomy custom field is for the users.

Comment: With your updated loop the $args are just ignored and all users are shown.

Comment: I start thinking that the taxonomy ACF field isn't supported.

Comment: That may be the reason. WP_User_Query will look only user and usermeta table. ACF Taxonomy has nothing to do with the user table.